# Linux環境でsystemctlやserviceコマンドが入っていない場合どうやってインストールする‌​か

Tags: linux, systemd

Dockerを使用してローカル環境を構築しています。
amazonlinuxコンテナを使用しているのですが、
systemctlやserviceコマンドが見つかりませんというエラーがでました。
調べたところパスが通っていないということではなく、
インストールされていないようでした。

下記のリンクを参考にするとDockerの中ではsystemdは動かさないのが普通とのことだったので
コマンド自体は必要ないのですが、インストールする方法が分からないので質問させていただきます。
[teratail - systemctlコマンドがない＞＜](https://teratail.com/questions/5969)

systemctlやserviceコマンドは通常どうやってインストールするのでしょうか？

```
yum install -y systemctl service
```

上記コマンドを打ってもコマンドをインストールすることができませんでしたので、
ご存知の方ご教授お願いします。

Comment: Dockerを使わないLinux環境ではsystemctlやserviceコマンドをどうやってインストールするのか、ということですか？

Comment: はいその通りです。Linux環境でsystemctlやserviceコマンドが入っていない場合どうやってインストールするかということになります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

systemctlコマンドはsystemdの制御に、serviceコマンドは旧来のinitシステムなどでサービスの操作に使うコマンドなので、それらのシステムと一緒にインストールされるものです。よってコマンドだけ単独でインストールすることはありませんし、入れても正しく動かないでしょう。

これらのコマンドが存在していなければ、そのコマンドを使わない構成<sup>*1</sup>になっているか、システムが正しくインストールされていないかのどちらかだと思います。

<sub>*1: 例えば旧来のinitを使うシステムにsystemctlは存在しません。initもsystemdも使わないコンテナイメージではどちらのコマンドも存在しません。</sub>

もちろん後からsystemdに切り替えることも可能でしょうが、システム全体に関わるプログラムですから、よほどの理由がなければそのまま使う方が無難です。

Answer (score 0):

serviceコマンド は sysvinit-utils パッケージの一部です。

```
apt-get install sysvinit-utils
```

もしかしたら, すでにインストール済みで /usr/sbin/service があるかもしれません。
PATHを追加したら、うまくいくかもしれません。

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```